# how to make an all arrays (including associative array) to single level of array using php?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, associative-array, hierarchy

Hope you can help me with this. Because I'm trying to reorder them but i need first to make the be at a single level of array. From associative array to single array.

```
$MY_ASSOC_ARRAY
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [MAIN_ID] => 1
            [ORDER] => 1
            [NAME] => Animal
            [PARENT_ID] => 0
            [childs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [MAIN_ID] => 4
                            [ORDER] => 4
                            [NAME] => doggie
                            [PARENT_ID] => 1
                            [childs] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [MAIN_ID] => 18
                                            [ORDER] => 18
                                            [NAME] => hunting
                                            [PARENT_ID] => 4
                                            [childs] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [MAIN_ID] => 21
                                                            [ORDER] => 21
                                                            [NAME] => setter
                                                            [PARENT_ID] => 18
                                                        )

                                                    [1] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [MAIN_ID] => 22
                                                            [ORDER] => 22
                                                            [NAME] => pointer
                                                            [PARENT_ID] => 18
                                                        )

                                                )
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [MAIN_ID] => 19
                                            [ORDER] => 19
                                            [NAME] => companion
                                            [PARENT_ID] => 4
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Alright now the array should not be in that multi level (associative) array instead it will look like this:

```
   Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [MAIN_ID] => 1
            [ORDER] => 1
            [NAME] => Animal
            [PARENT_ID] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [MAIN_ID] => 4
            [ORDER] => 4
            [NAME] => doggie
            [PARENT_ID] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [MAIN_ID] => 18
            [ORDER] => 18
            [NAME] => hunting
            [PARENT_ID] => 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [MAIN_ID] => 21
            [ORDER] => 21
            [NAME] => setter
            [PARENT_ID] => 18
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [MAIN_ID] => 22
            [ORDER] => 22
            [NAME] => pointer
            [PARENT_ID] => 18
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [MAIN_ID] => 19
            [ORDER] => 19
            [NAME] => companion
            [PARENT_ID] => 4
        )
)
```

I'm no sure how will that be possible in the most effecient way without using too much memory that will affect the speed with the use of Php Codeigniter. Thanks!

[UPDATE # 1]
here are the code that I have tried but the order is different

```
foreach($tree as $key => $value) {
    $single[] = $value;
}
```

And this is the output for this failed attemp...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [MAIN_ID] => 1
            [ORDER] => 1
            [NAME] => Animal
            [PARENT_ID] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [MAIN_ID] => 4
            [ORDER] => 4
            [NAME] => doggie
            [PARENT_ID] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [MAIN_ID] => 18
            [ORDER] => 18
            [NAME] => hunting
            [PARENT_ID] => 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [MAIN_ID] => 19
            [ORDER] => 19
            [NAME] => companion
            [PARENT_ID] => 4

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [MAIN_ID] => 21
            [ORDER] => 21
            [NAME] => setter
            [PARENT_ID] => 18
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [MAIN_ID] => 22
            [ORDER] => 22
            [NAME] => pointer
            [PARENT_ID] => 18
        )
)
```

The [NAME] => companion should be at the last array not on 4th ([3] => Array)

UPDATE # 2:

Feel bad about the down votes... if this question or problem is not useful on your end

Comment: Not sure, what have you tried to do so far.

Comment: How do you generate the array? Maybe it's possible to simply change that.

Comment: @RiggsFolly please check the update # 1 for the code that I have tried.

Comment: @PeterM has a very good suggestion

Comment: @PeterM the array is generated and has been adjusted by serveral function to make a heirarchy.

Comment: @RiggsFolly updated again the and the output is different....

Comment: Why? _The [NAME] => companion should be at the last array not on 4th ([3] => Array)_

Comment: @PeterM my problem is like from associative to sequential array without reordering... do you have any idea how to make this?

Comment: @PeterM my answer on why... because as you can see at the desired output the companion is at the last... but when I try to use the foreach (UPDATE # 1) it is now at 4th.

Comment: Sure I get that but what I'm trying to say is why would you need it in that way. What is the reason you need it to be sequential? If you simply wan't to show some of the information in a specific order it's not really needed to change the form of the array.

Comment: @PeterM anyway it is now solved thanks for your comments and input.

Comment: No problem, glad it's solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $array =  Array(
    0 => Array
        (
            'MAIN_ID' => 1,
            'ORDER' => 1,
            'NAME' => 'Animal',
            'PARENT_ID' => 0,
            'childs' => Array
                (
                    0 => Array
                        (
                            'MAIN_ID' => 4,
                            'ORDER' => 4,
                            'NAME' => 'doggie',
                            'PARENT_ID' => 1,
                            'childs' => Array
                                (
                                    0 => Array
                                        (
                                            'MAIN_ID' => 18,
                                            'ORDER' => 18,
                                            'NAME' => 'hunting',
                                            'PARENT_ID' => 4,
                                            'childs' => Array
                                                (
                                                    0 => Array
                                                        (
                                                            'MAIN_ID' => 21,
                                                            'ORDER' => 21,
                                                            'NAME' => 'setter',
                                                            'PARENT_ID' => 18,
                                                        ),

                                                    1 => Array
                                                        (
                                                            'MAIN_ID' => 22,
                                                            'ORDER' => 22,
                                                            'NAME' => 'pointer',
                                                            'PARENT_ID' => 18,
                                                        )

                                                )
                                        ),

                                    1 => Array
                                        (
                                            'MAIN_ID' => 19,
                                            'ORDER' => 19,
                                            'NAME' => 'companion',
                                            'PARENT_ID' => 4,
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
);
$out = [];
$out = generateArray($array, $out);
print_r($out);

function generateArray($in, $out){
    foreach($in as $value){
        $childs = false;
        if(isset($value['childs'])){
            $childs = $value['childs'];
            unset($value['childs']);
        }
        $out[] = $value;
        if($childs)
            $out = generateArray($childs, $out);
    }
    return $out;
}
?>
```